# How can I extract the .lp or .mps version of this (Rubik's cube example)

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/b192/_media/courses/ko/ilp_rubik.pdf

In pages 5-6 this example solves a cube with Gurobi. I don't have Gurobi but I'd like to get .lp or .mps version for my own testing?

Answer (score 4):

You can always use [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) as Omidi has indicated that will have some limitation on capacity. Exporting to different format is through `model.write()` function as explained [here](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032742051-How-do-I-export-a-model-from-Gurobi-) and refer [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/py_model_write.html)

Answer (score 3):

One possible way to use Gurobi is by invoking its library on [Google Colab](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409582394769-Google-Colab-Installation-and-Licensing).

> Google Colab provides an easy way to use Gurobi with Python + Jupyter
> notebooks, with no local software installation required. The Gurobi
> solver can be used in Colab notebooks either with the free
> size-limited trial license that is installed by default or with a Web
> License Service (WLS) license which enables the full features of
> Gurobi.

Also, as far as I know, Gurobi offers a [community license](https://www.gurobi.com/academia/for-online-courses/) to run the optimization problems, but with a limited size of the variables or constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I answer this

I Installed gurobipy and pycuber with pip.
I copied the python code to file.py
I replaced the last line

m.optimize()

with

m.write('model.lp')

m.write('model.mps')

Cbc cannot read those files but Scip can read .mps file.

Scip can read the exported .lp file after I deleted all [ and ] characters from the .lp file.

Done.